# dialogflow fullfilment and firebase response time

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a simple chatbot with `DialogFlow`.

My aim is to give information from user question, like : where can I slackline above water in croatia ? I have two parameters (`croatia`, `waterline`) and a list of slackline places.

So I need a data base to retrieve information from parameters. DialogFlow allows fulfillment with `Firebase`. I build a database with places (name, country, type of slack) and enable `webhook` call for my intent.

I use Inline Editor and **index.js**

```
const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;
var country = parameters.country.toString();

function show(snap) {
   console.log('snap');
   agent.add(JSON.stringify(snap.val(),null,2));
}

function slkplc(agent) {
     var testRef;
     firebase.database().ref('slackplace').once('value',show);
}

// Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('slack place', slkplc);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

But I do not get the expected result while trying it on DialogFlow or Google Assistant. The function show is asynchronously called but too late and the response is not available for **DialogFlow** :

[image: firebase log]

I see three way to deal with this problem :

1. use blocking call to database : another database ?
2. treat asynchronous message with DialogFlow ???
3. response to user that an error occured.

The third that I choose, but it is always on error.

After trying several things to wait data from database response, the only thing I managed is to freeze the response, therefore the timeout of DialogFlow - 5s -and Firebase - 60s - were reached.

**A workaround**

Another way to do it is to separate database acquisition and request/response from DialogFlow. The data of database is collected outside of the `dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment`

```
var data;
var inidata = firebase.database().ref().on('value',function(snap) {
     console.log('snap');
     data = snap.val();
 });

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
 ...
 function slkplc(agent) {
     agent.add(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
 }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('slack place', slkplc);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
}
```

Now I can do what I want with data, and I am able to find the place where I can practice waterline in croatia. But there is always something weird, the data of the database is duplicated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "right" solution is option 2 that you suggest: since you're doing an asynchronous call, you need to handle this correctly when working with the dialogflow-fulfillment library.

Basically, if your handler makes an asynchronous call, it needs to be asynchronous as well. To indicate to the `handleRequest()` method that your handler is async, you need to return a Promise object.

Firebase's `once()` method returns a Promise if you don't pass it a callback function. You can take advantage of this, *return that Promise*, and also handle what you want it to do as part of a `.then()` clause. It might look something like this:

```
function slkplc(agent) {
  var testRef;
  return firebase.database().ref('slackplace').once('value')
    .then( snap => {
      var val = snap.val();
      return agent.add( JSON.stringify( val, null, 2 ) );
    });
}
```

The important part isn't just that you use a Promise, but also that you return that Promise.

Comment: The behaviour is the same, the response is sent before the data is recovered, the only way I manage to make it work is to get data outside the request.

Comment: Handling it in a Promise *and returning the Promise* should work. Can you show code where you can illustrate it still isn't working, even when you return the Promise?

Comment: I 've tried again and it works now. Thank you for pointing out **returning** the Promise, that is the point I missed.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it to work. I've clarified my answer a bit to make sure it emphasizes returning the promise. If the answer helps you, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.